# Express update/delete routes are not working but no errors either

Tags: express, ejs

I'm learning node express by making a to-do list. I'm having trouble with marking a to-do as complete/incomplete and deleting them. It's not giving me any errors so I'm trying to console log wherever I can.

The `_id` in the database is console logging so I think I have my variables correct? Please see below the `server.js` and `main.js` files for the comments where I think could be wrong.

I've been stuck on this problem for 3 days now...

EDIT: I just noticed `findOneAndUpdate()` is a mongoose function. I don't have mongoose yet... I think I'm on the right track...

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const cors = require("cors");
const { request } = require("mongodb");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(cors());

const username = "hidden";
const password = "hidden";
const connectionString = `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@cluster0.7k2ww.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

MongoClient.connect(connectionString, { useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(
  (client) => {
    console.log("Connected to database");

    const db = client.db("to-do-list");
    const toDoCollection = db.collection("to-dos");

    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(express.static("public"));

    app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
      const result = await toDoCollection.find().toArray();
      const itemsLeft = await toDoCollection.countDocuments({
        done: false,
      });

      res.render("index.ejs", { todos: result, left: itemsLeft });
    });

    app.post("/addtodo", (req, res) => {
      toDoCollection
        .insertOne({ todo: req.body.todo, done: false })
        .then((result) => {
          res.redirect("/");
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    });

    app.put("/markComplete", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        await toDoCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            _id: req.body.todoId, // Is this line talking with my main.js file?
          },
          {
            $set: { done: true },
          },
          { sort: { _id: -1 }, upsert: false }
        );
        console.log(req.body.todoId);
        res.json("Task completed");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

    app.put("/markIncomplete", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        await toDoCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            _id: req.body.todoId,
          },
          {
            $set: { done: false },
          },
          { sort: { _id: -1 }, upsert: false }
        );
        console.log(req.body.todoId);
        res.json("Task completed");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

    app.delete("/deleteToDo", async (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body.todoId);
      try {
        await toDoCollection
          .findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.body.todoId })
          .then((result) => {
            console.log("todo deleted");
            res.json("todo deleted");
          });
      } catch {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  }
);
```

**main.js**

```
const deleteTask = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-todo");
const completeTask = document.querySelectorAll(".incomplete");
const incompleteTask = document.querySelectorAll(".complete");

Array.from(deleteTask).forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", deleteToDoFunc);
});

Array.from(completeTask).forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", completeToDoFunc);
});

Array.from(incompleteTask).forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", incompleteToDoFunc);
});


async function deleteToDoFunc() {
  console.log("Delete working!");
  const todoId = this.parentNode.dataset.id;
  console.log(todoId);

  try {
    const res = await fetch("deleteToDo", {
      method: "delete",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        todoId: todoId,
      }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    location.reload();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function completeToDoFunc() {
  console.log("Update working!");
  const todoId = this.parentNode.dataset.id;
  console.log(todoId);

  try {
    const res = await fetch("markComplete", {
      method: "put",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        todoId: todoId, // Is this line talking with the server.js file?
      }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    // location.reload();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function incompleteToDoFunc() {
  console.log("Incomplete task");
  const todoId = this.parentNode.dataset.id;

  console.log(todoId);

  try {
    const res = await fetch("markIncomplete", {
      method: "put",
      headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        todoId: todoId,
      }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    location.reload();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**index.ejs**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="../css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>To Do</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="flexContainer">
        <h1 class="title main-font center">To Do List</h1>
      </header>

      <form class="center" action="/addtodo" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add a To Do" name="todo" />
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        </button>
      </form>

      <div class="to-do-list flexContainer">
        <ul class="task-list center">
          <% todos.forEach(todo => { %>
          <li class="todo-name main-font complete-task" data-id="<%=todo._id%>"> <!-- The route should know which to-do to update/delete based on _id -->
            <% if (todo.done === true) { %>
            <span class="complete"><%= todo.todo %></span>
            <% } else { %>
            <span class="incomplete"><%= todo.todo %></span>
            <% } %>
            <span class="fa fa-trash delete-todo"></span>
          </li>
          <%}) %>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h2 class="main-font center">Left to do: <%= left %></h2>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to update your To-Do List, does it override everything in your document? I see that your using a PUT request instead of a PATCH request, and a PUT request would replace your all your data instead of updating a single field

Comment: Not sure what you mean by override. The PUT request are supposed to match the `_id` of the todo with the same id in the database. It worked previously when I used `todo = this.parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText;` to select the todo task. I wanted to try to find a way to do it with id because if there are two todos with the same text, the first one would be deleted. By using id, I could select the specific one.

Comment: I don't think this will solve your problem, but in this case I think you should be using the PATCH request. The put request should replace the data in your document, whereas your just trying to update 

https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Also when I tried making a similar app. I didn't use async await and it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.